# Download and parse textfile in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, download

So far I've kept app data on remote servers in the plist format. Downloading and parsing this format is relatively easy:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/data.plist"];
NSDictionary *plistData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

**How can I download a text file with an arbitrary format using Objective-C?**

An example of arbitrary format is a file that's two sections of CSV data separated by a few blank lines. Of course I'll know the format ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-[NSString initWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:`, like so

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/data.plist"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: url
                                                encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                   error: &error];
```

This will get you the file's contents which you can treat however you need to.

Comment: Note that this is a synchronous method and will block the thread.

Comment: @PauldeLange good point. I'm currently running the download in another thread via `performSelectorInBackground` as `dictionaryWithContentsOfURL` is synchronous as well.

Comment: I love this answer because it is (to the best of my understanding) 100% in memory so I don't have to save the file, parse it then delete it (which is onerous and annoying)